# Why does VecDeque's tail member point to the first element and not the last element?

Tags: rust

The [`VecDeque`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.44.0/src/liballoc/collections/vec_deque.rs#L54-L63) declaration:

```rust
pub struct VecDeque<T> {
    // tail and head are pointers into the buffer. Tail always points
    // to the first element that could be read, Head always points
    // to where data should be written.
    // If tail == head the buffer is empty. The length of the ringbuffer
    // is defined as the distance between the two.
    tail: usize,
    head: usize,
    buf: RawVec<T>,
}
```

Why does the comment say that `tail` points to the first element? I think it would be more natural that `head` and `tail` point to the first and last element, respectively.

If there is any historical reason for this, I want to know it.

Comment: why do you care ? that not public. head is where you data is write and is in "front" of the read pointer, so read is the tail and write is the head.

Comment: I'm just interested. Actually `tail` is referred when `push_front` is called. Is this something of a historical convention?

Comment: I get your confusion now. That boils down to personal preference, I'd assume.

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as "tail" pointing at the front, I'd think of it as "head" pointing to the start of the _unused_ space, and "tail" pointing the one past the end of the _unused_ space. As for _why_ I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelunking a bit finally led me to [the PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18747) in which [*huonw* has the exact same reaction you did](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18747/files#r20064979):

> I find this mapping weird: it seems like tail should be head (as in, that element is the head of the ringbuf) and vice versa.
>
> What's the motivation for having them this way around?

to which the PR author replies that it follows [the linux kernel terminology](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/circular-buffers.txt). Which never explains why it's using the terms it does.

The PR also specifically notes that

> `lo`, `nelts` [nb: the old names for these fields] are replaced by a more traditional `head` and `tail`

So the answer seems to be "because it follows traditional nomenclature". Might be that one original paper used these terms and it stuck, or could be happenstance. The internets certainly don't seem interested in this question as while the terms show up aplenty explanations don't.

The linux circular buffers document [was only added in 2010](https://lwn.net/Articles/380033/) so it would be documenting the existing state of affairs, and `struct circ_buf` called it that when the Git repo was created back in 2005, so if you want more you'd have to dive into the historical archive and hope there are references there.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `nelts` probably stands for `number of elements`, and that `lo` is for `lower end`. Then `lo` became `tail` (tails are lower than heads) and `lo + nelts` became `head`.

Comment: that why no one should follow tradition without question it first

Comment: After thinking about it more and re-reading the linux document I think it does make sense if you see the buffer as, say, a worm: you put things at the head, and you get them out of the tail. So head is where you insert content, and tail is where you get it out.

Answer (score 2):

> The “default” usage of this type as a queue is to use push_back to add to the queue, and pop_front to remove from the queue. extend and append push onto the back in this manner, and iterating over VecDeque goes front to back.

-- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html

This is the same as saying that the default usage is as a LIFO queue, with `head` pointing to the "first in" and `tail` pointing to the "last in". In that sense, the "default" chronological order of adding goes from head to tail. If we chose this frame of reference, the naming seems in order. This is the code author's frame of reference.

In contrast, the "default" chronological order of removing goes from tail to head. If we chose this frame of reference, the naming seems backward. This is the OP's frame of reference.

Both frames of reference are valid, but the code author's frame explains the naming. We could argue that since something has to be added before it can be removed, that adding to `head` is more natural, since it is the first action to change the state of the VecDeque.